# JPA stream with postgres driver

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm a little bit confused.

Say I gave a background task that need to iterate over large amount of data (a table with thousands of rows) using getResultStream() method on the JPA Query.

according to [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-stream-the-result-of-a-query-execution/) -

> On PostgreSQL and MySQL, the whole ResultSet is fetched at once even if the client does not navigate the entire ResultSet.

So I don't understand why the connection to DB remains open if I fetched the entire rows. In my code:

```
     Stream < Message > resultStream = outerEm.createQuery("Select m from Message m ", Message.class).getResultStream();
 resultStream.forEach(
         message - > {
             processMessage(message);
             logger.info("Connection is closed ? " + outerEm.unwrap(Session.class).doReturningWork(Connection::isClosed));
         }
```

the logs always printing : Connection is closed ? false

Comment: And why should it be closed? The fact that you use a stream or that those drivers choose to retrieve everything at once, doesn't mean you don't want to do other actions on that connection or session.

Comment: Since all data is fetched I don't need a db connection anymore . I can give it back to the pool.

Comment: You don't need it but that doesn't mean others don't. They might want to update the data, retrieve additional stuff. The fact that in this specific case for you it doesn't apply it doesn't mean it applies to everyone else.

Comment: You right. Thanx!!